# ERR_TIMED_OUT in Mac after a sleep

Tags: javascript

I'm facing this strange issue where the endpoints give ERR_TIMED_OUT when I open the mac after the it has been put to sleep (closed) for some time, around 10 to 20 minutes, while the browser with the website is running in background.

[image]

I tried using the event listeners online and offline but these doesn't seem to get triggered, I assume this is because the network connection is not being disrupted.

Is there any solution for handling this?

Note: It works perfectly after a refresh or if opened in a new tab. My ideal solution would be to trigger an event while the timeout happens.